# Update values in array of hashes conditionally

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

```
results = [
  {
    :id=>2,
    :start=> "3:30",
    break: 30,
    num_attendees: 14,
    hello: {hi: 1}
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    start: "3: 40",
    break: 40,
    num_attendees: {hi: 2},
    hello: 4
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    start: "4: 40",
    break: 10,
    num_attendees: 40
  }
]
```

Is there a better way of doing this by avoiding multiple `iteration`?

```
results.each do |hash|
  hash.each { |k, v|
    hash[k] = ""  if v.is_a? Hash
  } 
end


=> [{:id=>2, :start=>"3:30", :break=>30, :num_attendees=>14, :hello=>""}, {:id=>3, :start=>"3: 40", :break=>40, :num_attendees=>"", :hello=>4}, {:id=>4, :start=>"4: 40", :break=>10, :num_attendees=>40}]
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a question, or is this just a comment?

Comment: That's meant to be my question and I have edited the above now. Thanks

Comment: You don't need the `else hash[k] = v` leg of the logic since the value of `hash[k]` is already `v` in the body of your iterator.

Comment: There *may* be a slightly more compact way to write it, but I don't think there's any avoiding the iteration since you have to inspect every array element to determine if any of they keys is a `Hash`. You would need a specialized operation "set this value only if it's a `Hash`" which doesn't exist as a special Ruby method for a hash or array.

Comment: ah right. Can you give an example of the compact way please?

Comment: Well, I said *may*. I didn't have one in mind. I think your embedded `each` construct is the best you can do.  `results.each { |h| h.each { |k, v| h[k] = ""  if v.is_a? Hash } }`